# C# Exception while calling method on Dynamic Class

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, casting

While casting an object from a Dynamic Class, I'm getting the following error:

```
[A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ParameterHelper] 
cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ParameterHelper]. 


Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' 
in the context 'LoadNeither' 
at location 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.Net\\assembly\\GAC_32\\mscorlib\\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\\mscorlib.dll'. 

Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' 
in the context 'LoadNeither' 
at location 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.Net\\assembly\\GAC_32\\mscorlib\\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\\mscorlib.dll'.
```

The objects are both from the same type:

```
public class ParameterHelper
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Type type { get; set; }
}
```

I have compiled this class into a .DLL and added it as reference in the compiled class, the compiler gives no errors whatsoever. Another call, returning a String does work.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Why do you think this is `Dynamic`? Also, when you moved the `ParameterHelper` class did you delete the previous version of it so that it's not ambiguous?

Comment: @DavidPine I'm compiling a plain-text file to a class in memory, the type is `dynamic`, when calling it. The `ParameterHelper` is both in .DLL for the `dynamic` and in .CS for the application itself (as they both use it). You are suggesting to add a reference to the compiled .DLL and using this one instead of the .CS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.cs` file from the project to solve the ambiguous error.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are not trying to cast a `List<dynamic>` to `List<ParameterHelper>`?

What happens if you use something like

```
mylist.OfType<ParameterHelper>()
```

Comment: No, I'm doing exactly this:
`dynamic obj = compile.Compile(); //compiles .txt//
string name = obj.getPluginName(); //works//
List<ParameterHelper> e = obj.getParamWithType(); //error//`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, need more info. 
What is compile? an Expression?
Are you trying to compile some c# code at runtime?